# PostCreate/Hook on User Registration

Tags: users, 9

I want to hook into user registration but there doesn't seem to be any hook for it anymore. This is what I see from Drupal 8.8:

*hook_user_cancel

hook_user_cancel_methods_alter

hook_user_format_name_alter

hook_user_login

hook_user_logout*

Furthermore I can't find any events for it neither.

So how can I hook into user registration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends from what exactly the code needs to achieve.
[`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/9.1.x) and [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/9.1.x) are still used from Drupal 9, and they can be used to hook into account registration before users can enter values for the account to create. They should not be used to add an entity field, or add a validation handler for an entity, for which [`hook_entity_base_field_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_base_field_info/9.1.x) and [`hook_entity_bundle_field_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_field_info/9.1.x) (to add entity fields to an entity) or [`hook_entity_type_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_alter/9.1.x) (to add constrains to validate an entity) are preferable.

If you are instead looking for the Drupal 9 equivalent of Drupal 7 [`hook_user_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7.x), [`hook_user_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7.x), and [`hook_user_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7.x), which are invoked after the users entered the account data (and they should not be used to invalidate the entered data), they are still used, but they are documented under [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/9.1.x), [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/9.1.x), and [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/9.1.x). When you implement those hooks, you replace *ENTITY_TYPE* with *user*, for the User entity. This means that the name of the function implementing those hooks for the User entity doesn't change respect of the function name used in Drupal 7; it's just a matter of documentation.

Note also that the generic hooks, invoked for every entity implemented in Drupal, for example [`hook_entity_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7.x) are still used in Drupal 9. (See [`hook_entity_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/9.1.x).) The documentation page for that hook for Drupal 9 contains a reference to the equivalent hook invoked for a single entity type (*See also `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`*, written on two lines).

#### Further reading

- [Drupal Entity Validation API: Create Custom Entity Constraints](https://jigarius.com/blog/drupal-entity-validation-api)
- [Documentation for entity hooks has been consolidated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2294409)

Answer (score 3):

Users are entities in Drupal 8/9.  So you have [hook_entity_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/8.9.x) and [hook_entity_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.9.x).

Just replace `entity` with `user`.

Also, note that `hook_entity_presave` is called on every entity save, so if you want to do preprocessing before saving a user on registration, you need to check if the user is new:

```
function MYMODULE_user_presave(UserInterface $user) {
  if ($user->isNew()) {
    // Do stuff for newly registered users.
  }
```